# Creating a C# program that works with an existing Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, excel-2010

firstly I'm not even sure if its even possible so i thought id ask
all research that i have done haven't given me the answers and info I need.

I need to create a VS Win forms program (using visual studio 2012) that interacts with a DB & AN EXCEL 2010 WORKBOOK?
can it be reasonably done?

the specifics are these

1. the excel 2010 workbook already exists and comprises 35 sheets/pages, BUT NOT ALL PAGES NEED TO BE USED IN THE PROGRAM only 12 do. it is a workbook for project management
2. the program works with button click events, that when pressed would open a specific page/sheet of the workbook. the user would then be able to fill in fields etc and save it
   ideally also print it(Specific page)  (from program and not excel directly) and obviously access it and amend or add to it from the Program time and time again
3. the workbook is a master workbook so every time a new project is created, the program would need to generate a new "instance" of the master workbook (the 12 pages)
4. each project and the "instance" of the workbook would need to be saved separately on the Hard Drive
5. this is/would be a client side stand alone application running on a laptop

is this possible? or highly complex?
and if so what are the relevant classes that would need to be imported into the project

or is it better/possible? to take the relevant pages ad make a new workbook inside of visual studio office node and make instances of it ??

at no point at all does data in the DB or Excel workbook need to be transferred to one another. they run separately but are part of the one program

any and all help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complex project, visual studio supports Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. You can import the library and start using the events built in. It works great with excel. I have created numerous projects just like the one you've mentioned and had no problems so far.

Try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151) link

Comment: Hi Xtechkid thanks for the helpful reply. the link you have given me is for visual basic and i need to do this in C# or visual studio, i don't know VB. is there something for C#? or better yet how about an email address so that i can send you a more detailed email?

Comment: also this is my first attempt at doing this, i've only been coding for 8 months and am lost as to how to even begin!